# Gekko is not respecting the restrictions of the variables

Tags: python, pandas, gekko

Gekko is not respecting the restrictions, and because of that is not being able to find the same solutions as excel solver for example.

**Here is the problem to solve, a minimization of errors**

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
obj = 0
obj2 = 0
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
v0 = m.Var(0.002, -0.005, 0.005)
v1 = m.Var(0.004, -0.005, 0.005)
v2 = m.Var(0.002, -0.005, 0.005)
v3 = m.Var(0.002, -0.005, 0.005)
v4 = m.Var(0.002, -0.005, 0.005)
v5 = m.Var(0.001, -0.005, 0.005)
v6 = m.Var(0.003, -0.005, 0.005)
v7 = m.Var(-0.005, -0.005, 0.005)
v8 = m.Var(-0.002, -0.005, 0.005)
v9 = m.Var(-0.001, -0.005, 0.005)
y = []
y.append(v0)
y.append(v1)
y.append(v2)
y.append(v3)
y.append(v4)
y.append(v5)
y.append(v6)
y.append(v7)
y.append(v8)
objetivos = []
obj = 0
pq = []
p = ponderaciones[:9]
p2 = ponderaciones[9:]
r = rentabilidades[:9]
r2 = rentabilidades[9:]
for j in range(len(r2) + len(r)):
    if j < (len(r)):
        obj += p[j]/(1+y[j])*r[j]
    else:
        iterator = j - len(r)
        obj += p2[iterator]*r2[iterator]
objetivos.append(obj)
pq.append(obj)
a = np.array(objetivos)
b = un_pickle
print(b[0])
z = (np.sum(b[0]- a[0]))**2
m.Minimize(z)
m.solve(disp=False)
print(y)
print('Objective = '+str(m.options.objfcnval*1000000000/5))
```

I tried to restrict the variables by doing this,

`yb = m.Array(m.Var, 0.004, lb = -0.005, ub = 0.005)`

but it didn't work either.

The final solution and the variables end like this

```
[[0.00039421467367], [0.00078856597697], [0.00039428301399], [0.00039428298849], [0.00039428298849], [0.00019714149424], [0.00059142448273], [-0.00096599525378], [-0.0003942834613]]
Objective = 9.2421428926
```

I'm not sure why the restrictions are not working.

For recreating the problem, i restricted the amount of data, but in the complete case **ponderaciones** and **rentabilidades** are dictionaries with many DF insides, in this case they are only a series each.

```
ponderaciones = pd.Series({'ACC': 0.07645771,
 'UAA': 0.0,
 'EOAO': 0.000712,
 'CIA': 0.0055,
 'BJA': 0.01,
 'BOEA': 0.03,
 'UA': 0.110,
 'EOA': 0.0712,
 'CI': 0.00557,
 'BJ': 0.0161,
 'BOE': 0.0355,
 'U': 0.0553,
 'E': 0.00071231,
 'C': 0.005555,
 'B': 0.0157,
 'E': 0.0335}
)

rentabilidades = pd.Series({'ACC': 0.0035323168,
 'UAA': 0.033975,
 'EOAO': -0.0016047,
 'CIA': -0.00248652,
 'BJA': -0.0075425,
 'BOEA': 0.0016429,
 'UA': 0.550,
 'EOA': 0.0512,
 'CI': 0.00157,
 'BJ': 0.0861,
 'BOE': 0.0555,
 'U': 0.0593,
 'E': 0.00231,
 'C': 0.0555,
 'B': 0.07,
 'E': 0.05
})

un_pickle = [0.00119,  0.00107,  0.0013,  0.00105,  0.00182]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script gives a solution that is within the bounds `-0.005<y<0.005` for all variables. One potential reason that the bounds are not observed is that the solver failed to find a solution. Switching to `disp=True` displays the solver output to ensure that a successful solution is found.

```
EXIT: Optimal Solution Found.

 The solution was found.

 The final value of the objective function is  0.005269679643169275
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  IPOPT (v3.12)
 Solution time  :  0.011 sec
 Objective      :  0.005269679643169275
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

```
[[0.00080192314638], [0.00066898310209], [0.00033248534634], [0.00031046466289], \
[0.00020163446647], [0.00025390495361], [0.004994273964], [0.0049445497412], \
[-0.00031911076974]]
Objective = 1053935.92864
```

One other thing to check is that the objective function is defined correctly.

```py
z = (np.sum(b[0]- a[0]))**2
m.Minimize(z)
```

This statement is a summation of only one value with the square `**2` on the outside of the summation. If it is sum of squared errors, the square is typically performed before the summation. In this case, it doesn't change the problem outcome because `b[0]` and `a[0]` are only one value and expression.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
obj = 0
obj2 = 0

ponderaciones = pd.Series({'ACC': 0.07645771,
 'UAA': 0.0,
 'EOAO': 0.000712,
 'CIA': 0.0055,
 'BJA': 0.01,
 'BOEA': 0.03,
 'UA': 0.110,
 'EOA': 0.0712,
 'CI': 0.00557,
 'BJ': 0.0161,
 'BOE': 0.0355,
 'U': 0.0553,
 'E': 0.00071231,
 'C': 0.005555,
 'B': 0.0157,
 'E': 0.0335}
)

rentabilidades = pd.Series({'ACC': 0.0035323168,
 'UAA': 0.033975,
 'EOAO': -0.0016047,
 'CIA': -0.00248652,
 'BJA': -0.0075425,
 'BOEA': 0.0016429,
 'UA': 0.550,
 'EOA': 0.0512,
 'CI': 0.00157,
 'BJ': 0.0861,
 'BOE': 0.0555,
 'U': 0.0593,
 'E': 0.00231,
 'C': 0.0555,
 'B': 0.07,
 'E': 0.05
})

un_pickle = [0.00119,  0.00107,  0.0013,  0.00105,  0.00182]

m = GEKKO(remote=False)
v0 = m.Var(0.002, -0.005, 0.005)
v1 = m.Var(0.004, -0.005, 0.005)
v2 = m.Var(0.002, -0.005, 0.005)
v3 = m.Var(0.002, -0.005, 0.005)
v4 = m.Var(0.002, -0.005, 0.005)
v5 = m.Var(0.001, -0.005, 0.005)
v6 = m.Var(0.003, -0.005, 0.005)
v7 = m.Var(-0.005, -0.005, 0.005)
v8 = m.Var(-0.002, -0.005, 0.005)
v9 = m.Var(-0.001, -0.005, 0.005)
y = []
y.append(v0)
y.append(v1)
y.append(v2)
y.append(v3)
y.append(v4)
y.append(v5)
y.append(v6)
y.append(v7)
y.append(v8)
objetivos = []
obj = 0
pq = []
p = ponderaciones[:9]
p2 = ponderaciones[9:]
r = rentabilidades[:9]
r2 = rentabilidades[9:]
for j in range(len(r2) + len(r)):
    if j < (len(r)):
        obj += p[j]/(1+y[j])*r[j]
    else:
        iterator = j - len(r)
        obj += p2[iterator]*r2[iterator]
objetivos.append(obj)
pq.append(obj)
a = np.array(objetivos)
b = un_pickle
print(b[0])
z = (np.sum(b[0]- a[0]))**2
m.Minimize(z)
m.solve(disp=True)
print(y)
print('Objective = '+str(m.options.objfcnval*1000000000/5))
```

Comment: Good point, yes now i'm getting a viable solution, but i'm not able to find the same solution using scipy or even excel solver. I changed the function objective as i was missing that parenthesis for the original problem. 

There is a way to know what value is taking z, in the original problem there are many others z, so it will be very helpful to know the values to start debugging.

The original function looks like, m.Minimize(z+z1+z2+z3+z4)

Comment: The objective function is also very small. Perhaps try scaling the objective or else setting the solver tolerance to a smaller value such as `m.options.RTOL=1e-10` and `m.options.OTOL=1e-10`. If the solver reports a successful solution then it may be a local minimum. Try different initial guesses as well.